# jQuery extracting value of a custom attribute in <option> field

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay so for example I have declared a custom value in a select for for example

```
<select id="something">
    <option value="1" data="01"></option>
    <option value="2" data="02"></option>
    <option value="3" data="03"></option>
    <option value="4" data="04"></option>
</select>
```

For some reason I cannot use the `value` attribute here. I need to use `data` attribute to extract the value. I tried using jquery as below:

```
var dataString = {
    clicks: $("#clicks").val($(this).find(':selected').attr('data'))
};
```

But this  is not returning the result as expected. In console its showing `too much recursion`. I am not getting the value of the `data` attribute here (01, 02, 03 etc). Please help.

Comment: please see the updated question once...

Comment: i have post answer.. try this

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed attribute which can be accessed using `.data()`

```js
console.log($("#something option:selected").data("value"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="something">
        <option value="1" data-value="01"></option>
        <option value="2" data-value="02"></option>
        <option value="3" data-value="03"></option>
        <option value="4" data-value="04"></option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 <select id="selectNo">
           <option value="1" data-no="01">1</option>
           <option value="2" data-no="02">2</option>
           <option value="3" data-no="03">3</option>
           <option value="4" data-no="04">4</option>
        </select>
```

And Jquery

```
  $("#selectNo").change(function () {
         alert($(this).find(':selected').data("no"));
    });
```

[Output](https://jsfiddle.net/ed5axgvk/126/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume `this` is your dropdown. Try the following:

```
$("#clicks").val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('data'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#something').change(function(e) {
    //var id = $(this).val();
  $('#something :selected').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).data('id');
        
        alert(value); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="something">
    <option value="1" data-id="01"></option>
    <option value="2" data-id="02"></option>
    <option value="3" data-id="03"></option>
    <option value="4" data-id="04"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like below.

`var option = $("#something option:selected").attr("data-value");`

**Exp:**

```js
 $("#something").change(function () {
  console.log($("#something option:selected").attr("data-value")) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="something">
        <option value="1" data-value="01">01</option>
        <option value="2" data-value="02">02</option>
        <option value="3" data-value="03">03</option>
        <option value="4" data-value="04">04</option>
</select>
```